# c# Retrieve details from more than one csv file in a folder

Tags: c#

My csv file looks like below, I need to retrieve the values of Folder_NAME, File_NAME and File_VERSION in a coma separated format

```
Folder_NAME,KTDPAUTOMATION_AdminUI_AUTODRB
File_NAME,DSW_CBI_EVAL_C4226367
File_VERSION,1.0
File_DISPLAY_NAME_TYPE,FileNAME
File_OFFSET_TYPE,FFF
```

Comment: please read [ask]. you will need to write some code to show some attempt at this.

Comment: Agree with Tim. And don't forget to post some of the data too ! You have posted a header, no content. This question cannot be answered without an example of your csv content. Are commas allowed in file names ? in that case, any string quotes should be parsed properly to decide data columns for each csv line..

Comment: Are there one value per row? Are the rows always 5 per record?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\yourdir")
.Select(fileName => File.ReadLines(fileName))
.Select(line => line.Split(' ')
.Select(tuple => 
    tuple.Split(',')
    .ToDictionary(arr => arr[0], arr => arr[1])))
.SelectMany(dict => 
   new {
      FolderName = dict["Folder_NAME"],
      FileName = dict["File_NAME"],
      FileVersion = dict["File_VERSION"]
   })
```

Your file does not seem to be comma separated values (csv), but key value pairs that where the key and value are separated by commas and the pairs are separated by space.

About Comma separated values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values